Does Windows 11 have a 32,767 character limit for environment variables?
(See also: Why does Windows have a limit on environment variables at all?)
According to the Windows app development documentation, “The maximum size of a user-defined environment variable is 32,767 characters.” I created a Rust package that tests that limit. To my surprise, I was able to create an environment variable that is much longer that 32,767 characters.

Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "big-variable-test"
edition = "2021"

[[bin]]
name = "big-variable-creator"
path = "src/big_variable_creator.rs"

[[bin]]
name = "big-variable-size-checker"
path = "src/big_variable_size_checker.rs"

src\big_variable_creator.rs:
// This is the largest number that I’ve gotten to work. It’s much larger than the limit that the
// documentation stated.
const MAX_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_LENGTH: usize = 999999999;

fn main() {
    std::process::Command::new("cargo")
        .args(["run", "--bin", "big-variable-size-checker"])
        .env("BIG_VARIABLE", "A".repeat(MAX_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_LENGTH))
        .spawn()
        .expect("cargo should have started")
        .wait()
        .expect("cargo should be running");
}

src\big_variable_size_checker.rs:
fn main() {
    let number_of_chars = std::env::var("BIG_VARIABLE")
        .expect("BIG_VARIABLE should be set")
        .chars()
        .count();
    println!("{}", number_of_chars);
}


When I run cargo run --bin big-variable-creator, I can see that it’s able to create an environment variable that’s 999,999,999 characters long. After doing some more research, I found a post on a Microsoft Developer Blog that says:

This program creates an environment block that holds only one variable, named x whose value is 131,067 copies of the letter x. It’s not glamourous, and certainly not useful, but it does show that Windows is fine with it.


Does Windows 11 truly have a 32,767 character limit for environment variables, or does that only apply to older versions of Windows? Is there anything that stops working if you create an environment variable that large?

“Does Windows 11 truly have a 32,767 character limit for environment variables?” - Yes; Just because you can create a variable with more characters doesn’t mean the behavior won’t be undefined beyond 32,767 characters. Why exactly do you need a variable with more than 32,767 characters?

I don’t need an environment variable with more than 32,767 characters. I’m trying to install Descent 3 in Wine. Sometimes, when I run the installer in Wine, it page faults almost immediately. Other times, it works fine. After a lot of troubleshooting, my hypothesis is that the installer page faults if GetEnvironmentStringsW() returns an environment block that is larger than 32,767 code units. I started working on a program to test my hypothesis, and I was surprised to see that my test program could create variables that large. How do you know that the answer to my question is yes?
